# javascript redirect only works in IE after showing the IE dev console

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, redirect, console

I came across the weirdest bug. All i wanted to do is send a form using jquery and in the callback redirect the user to another page, like:

window.location.href = "index.php?p=admin";

Which from what i can find should work in all browsers.

And it does, except in IE8/9 where it only does that after i hit F12 to show the dev console! After that i need to close the browser for the redirect to NOT work again.

Anyone know why this happens and know a better way to redirect to another local page using javascript that works in IE without being affected by this crazy bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using any of the console. functions? They aren't defined until showing the dev console and will stop the script from executing.

Comment: A good tip is to define `console.log` if it doesn't exist, that way you're safe on all platforms

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
window.location.replace("index.php?p=admin");
```

Comment: thanks, i did. the problem was console.log calls stopping script execution.